# How to use the iot lab platform and how to choose the right nodes

Tags: iot, robotics, riot-os

I want to create an Iot-project where I am gonna have to create a watering system.
I am going to use Riot-OS on an ESP32 or ESP8266 that will interact with a water pump, n-mosfet, power supply and a humidity sensor.
At the same time I will have a Linux webserver running accepting the data from this controller.

Until my hardware arrives I want to test the code using iot-lab. However, I do not know what nodes I have to use and why. How do I choose the correct ones?
Do I also need an .elf file for the sensor, like in this tutorial https://www.iot-lab.info/earn/ is being used for the lamp ?

Also, regarding if I use the ssh keygen command and then the copy paste and the connect to the experiment is the only thing that I need to do in order to run my code properly??

Is there a good tutorial that explains those things because I did not find any ?

Comment: "I am goin to use riot os in linux that will be my server" 
Are you saying  that you're going to run Riot on native (which is possible) to use this as a server? What's the point of that? Why not run it in Linux without the Riot environment?

Comment: @Opifex Because it is a project and they told me to do it this way, using riot in linux.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't mean that you're supposed to program riot in Linux, and then flash it on your esp32? With a Linux server running alongside of it?

Comment: @Opifex That is what I was trying to say actually ! Maybe I said it in a confusing way

Comment: I edited your question to clear up some confusion. After being approved it will be visible to you (I'm guessing it should not take more than 30 minutes). Feel free to undo my changes if they do not reflect what you intended to ask.
Also a tip in general: try to only ask one thing at a time. You will get better answers that way. 
You can read how to ask good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use IoT lab, you only can use the `Pycom FiPy`.

> Until my hardware arrives I want to test the code using iot-lab.
> However, I do not know what nodes I have to use and why. How do I
> choose the correct ones? Do I also need an .elf file for the sensor,
> like in this tutorial https://www.iot-lab.info/earn/ is being used for
> the lamp ?

Just follow the [getting started guide.](https://doc.riot-os.org/getting-started.html) That should do the job.
`make flash` is generating the elf and flashs it. I recommend the target `native` for development. `BOARD=native make flash term` in order to also see the serial output. It has a proper IP stack (when configured with `tapsetup`) and works well enough for development. At least for the networking part. When you need to interact with the hardware, you have to use the actual hardware, of course. IoTLab is only useful, if you have big routing simulations etc. IoTLab also doesn't have the water pump etc. you need.

> Is there a good tutorial that explains those things because I did not find any ?

Checkout the [RIOT OS examples](https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/tree/master/examples).
`gnrc networking` and `saul` are interesting for you, I guess.
You should also read the [SAUL documentation](https://riot-os.org/api/group__drivers__saul.html).